# Como puedo rellenar un ArrayList de un objeto de una clase ya creado

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, clase, objeto

les comento tengo dos clases, una clase de tipo Tarea y otro de tipo Persona, dentro de los atributos de tipo persona, tiene un ArrayList de tipo Tarea,
cuando yo creo un objeto de tipo Tarea, y al rellenar este objeto con sus atributos.

```
     public class Persona {

private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String clave;
private String usuario;
private ArrayList<Tareas> tareaTrabajo;
```

lo que yo quiero es agregar al objeto de tipo persona, mas objetos dentro de su ArrayList de tipo Tarea.

ejemplo:

```
Tarea jugar=new Tarea("pc", "Sims");
Tarea dormir=new Tarea("Casa","2 horas");

ArrayList<Tarea> misTareas=new ArrayList<Tarea>();
misTareas.add(jugar);
misTareas.add(dormir)
Usuario user1=new Usuario("usuario 1", "Javier", "Gallardo", "Informatica","123",misTareas);
```

// Intento 1: me da error

```
Tarea trabajar=new Tarea("cine","7 horas");

user1.getTareaTrabajo().add(trabajar);
```

// Intento 2: reemplaza todo lo guardado por el nuevo ArrayList creado

```
Tarea viajar=new Tarea(". . . ",". . . ");

ArrayList<Tareas>tarea1=new ArrayList<>();
tarea1.add(viajar);

user1.setTareaTrabajo(tarea1);
```

Espero por favor su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se muy bien que error te da, ya que no comentas nada de la salida.
En principio lo único que he visto en el código es que al mostrar la clase de Persona, en principio nos has mostrado 5 atributos y en el constructor de ésta tienes 6, no se si tienes otro campo como variable de clase que no has mostrado.

En el resto del código parece que estás ejecutando bien los métodos. Así que, si no es lo que he comentado arriba muestra el error que te produce al ejecutarla. De todos modos te dejo el código de lo que yo he probado:
Creación de tareas

```
//Creacion de Tareas
        Tarea jugar = new Tarea ("pc" , "1h");
        Tarea trabajar = new Tarea ("programar" , "7h");
        Tarea dormir = new Tarea ("dormir" , "6h");
```

Creación del ArrayList

```
//ArrayList de tareas
ArrayList<Tarea> tareasProgramadas = new ArrayList<Tarea>();
```

Creación de Persona.

```
//Creacion de persona
Persona persona2 = new Persona("Luis" , "Gallardo" , "usuario2" , "123", tareasProgramadas);
```

Si lo que quieres es añadir un segundo ArrayList al que ya tienes definido en la clase Persona. Deberías recorrer el nuevo ArrayList e ir ejecutando el método add del ArrayList que obtienes de getTareaTrabajo().

```
//Creo un segundo ArrayList, al que le he metido las mismas tareas que el primero por comodidad
ArrayList<Tarea> tareasProgramadas2 = tareasProgramadas;

//For each que recorre tareasProgramadas2 y lo mete en el ArrayList almacenado en personas
        for(Tarea t:tareasProgramadas2){
            persona2.getListaTareas().add(t);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema en tu código es el siguiente:

```
public class Persona {

.
.
.
private ArrayList<Tareas> tareaTrabajo;
```

Donde si observas el arraylist estás definiendo que lleva objetos del tipo `Tareas`

en el código que pones después

```
ArrayList<Tarea> misTareas=new ArrayList<Tarea>();
```

estás definiendo que lleva objetos del tipo `Tarea`

Como `Tarea` y `Tareas` no son lo mismo por eso falla.